# Insert row into table based on condition

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an package where am inserting XML data into record set destination and from record set destination to database table via `Execute SQL` task

My XML contains data like

```
<ROOT>
<row firstName="Joe" lastName="Blow" city="Seattle" state="WA" phone="555-666-7777"/>
<row firstName="Jane" lastName="Doe" city="Los Angeles" state="CA" phone="566-866-2345"/>
<row firstName="Robert" lastName="Smith" city="Washington" state="DC" phone="444-555-6666"/>
<row firstName="Mary" lastName="Contrary" city="Garden City" state="FL" phone="234-876-9374"/>
<row firstName="Thomas" lastName="Doubter" city="New Orleans" state="LA" phone="384-389-7342"/>
<row firstName="Barbara" lastName="Bologna" city="Chicago" state="IL" phone="483-483-8162"/>
</ROOT>
```

and I have taken four variables in my package all of string type

```
firstname,lastname,city,state,phone
```

Now my requirement is I need to insert this XML data into my destination table based on first name..

If I have chosen `firstname= Robert`, only row with that first name have to be entered into my destination table.

And my execute sql task contains

```
Result set Property--single row  
connection type--OLEDB  
connection--myconnection  
sql statement--declare @firstName varchar(25)
select @firstName= ?
INSERT INTO people_xml (firstName, lastName,city,state,phone) 
  select firstName,lastName, city,state,phone from people_xml 
  where firstName=@firstName

Select Convert(varchar,Scope_Identity()) as SourceIDentity
```

Parameter mapping Tab

```
user::firstname  
user::lastname  
user::city  
user::state
user::phone
```

result set Tab

```
result Name--0
variable Name--User::SourceID
```

When I am running the package it is throwing an error like

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "declare @firstName varchar(25)
>   select @firstName= ..." failed with the following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB 
>   operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No 
>   work was done.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not
>   established correctly.

Comment: StackOverflow works on the premise that people want to help each other. A measure of a person's helpfulness & perceived influence on a topic is related to their reputation. You have asked **[5 other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1025057/satishkumar?tab=questions)** but not selected an answer nor have you upvoted useful answers. People are happy to spend their energy helping you find the answers but you need to be a good member of the community and reward their efforts with votes or feedback if their solutions are not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this error is that is very generic. Personally I got this error twice. Once I solved it by matching the fields LENGTHS. For example, I used varchar(80) in the table and varchar(50) or so when inserting. I solved it by using the same type AND length.

The second time I was in real trouble but thankfully there was one guy that had the same problem than me: I had to register sqltaskconnections.dll using regsvr32. Search for it on the internet, you will find a guide there.

If I were you, I'd give it a try. As I said before, this error is really generic and unless someone really wise answers, my guess is that you'll have to struggle a lot =-(

Hope this helps!